# find word combinations based on order from a list

Tags: python, list, combinations, permutation

I have a list of words like the following:

`[w1, w2, w3, w4]` (N words).

What i want to get is combinations starting from left:

```
w1, w1w2, w1w2w3, w1w2w3w4, w2, w2w3, w2w3w4, w3, w3w4, w4
```

is there a pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Did you *try* anything?

Comment: So `w1w3` is not among you desired output?

Comment: what ive tried consists of two loops. i'm looking for a better and faster way when the list is huge

Comment: @schwobaseggl thats right. thats something i dont want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a nested comprehension

```
l = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
[''.join(l[x:y]) for x in range(len(l)) for y in range(x + 1, len(l) + 1)]
# ['1', '12', '123', '1234', '2', '23', '234', '3', '34', '4']
```

or you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to shorten it

```
from itertools import combinations
[''.join(l[x:y]) for x, y in combinations(range(len(l) + 1), 2)]
# or to get lists:
[l[x:y] for x, y in combinations(range(len(l) + 1), 2)]
```

Comment: can this be converted to list of lists using combinations? : `[['w1', 'w1w2', 'w1w2w3', 'w1w2w3w4'],[ 'w2', 'w2w3', 'w2w3w4'], ['w3', 'w3w4'], ['w4']]`

Comment: @AbhishekThakur You can do  `[[''.join(l[x:y]) for y in range(x + 1, len(l) + 1)] for x in range(len(l))]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way...

```
l1 = ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4']
str = ''
i=0

while i < len(l1):
    str=''
    for j in range(i,len(l1)):
        str+= l1[j]
        print(str)
    i+=1
```

Output

```
w1
w1w2
w1w2w3
w1w2w3w4
w2
w2w3
w2w3w4
w3
w3w4
w4
```

Comment: Misses out w2, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done in a straightforward manner using two (nested) for loops:

```
words = ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4']
for i in range(len(words)):
    for j in range(i, len(words)):
        print("".join(words[i:j+1])) # take all the words between i and j and concatenate them
```

**OUTPUT**

```
w1
w1w2
w1w2w3
w1w2w3w4
w2
w2w3
w2w3w4
w3
w3w4
w4
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`itertools.accumulate()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.accumulate) approach:

```
import itertools

l = ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w4']
result = [s for i in range(len(l)) for s in itertools.accumulate(l[i:], lambda t,w: t + w)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['w1', 'w1w2', 'w1w2w3', 'w1w2w3w4', 'w2', 'w2w3', 'w2w3w4', 'w3', 'w3w4', 'w4']
```